# Array filter linq does not return expected result

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I'm trying to get **existCount** from an **array**, which has **id** in selected array.

But something went wrong, I had an item with id = 5493 but **existCount.length = 0**

My JS code:

[image]

Chrome Console view:

[image]

Where my fault?

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the types of `item.id` and `script.script_id`, you're comparing numbers and strings.

```
item.id  script_id
  |         |
  v         v
5493 === "5493" -> false
```

```js
console.log(5493 === "5493");
```

An alternative is converting to number the `script_id`

*This approach uses the `+` to convert that string to number and make the correct comparison*

```js
console.log(5493 === +"5493");
```

*This is an example to illustrate.*

```js
var array = [{id: 4110, name: "Ele"}, {id: 4091, name: "SO"}, {id: 5493, name: "Target"}];

var script_id = "5493";
var result = array.filter(e => e.id === +script_id);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```